# Prolog if/else statement with "or" condition

Tags: if-statement, prolog

I'm new to Prolog, and I'm trying to write an if/else statement with an "or" condition.  So to demonstrate, I want something like:

```
 gothrough([H|T], B, C):-
    (  T == [] or H == 'then'  %if either the tail is an empty list or if H == "then", do the following%
    -> append(H,B,B), outputs(B,C)
    ;  append(H,B,B), gothrough(T, B, C) %else%
    ).
```

This implementation doesn't work however; is there an obvious way to do this that I'm not getting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, use ";" for or and "," for and.

```
gothrough([H|T], B, C):-
    (  (T == [] ; H == 'then')  %if either the tail is an empty list or if H == "then", do the following%
    -> append(H,B,B), outputs(B,C)
    ;  append(H,B,B), gothrough(T, B, C) %else%
    ).
```

Notice that **append(H, B, B)** always fails when H is different of [].

You can write

```
 gothrough([H|T], B, C):-
    append(H,B,B), 
    (  (T == [] ; H == 'then')  %if either the tail is an empty list or if H == "then", do the following%
    -> outputs(B,C)
    ;  gothrough(T, B, C) %else%
    ).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!  Can you please clarify what you mean by always fails when H is different of []?

Comment: append chains lists, for example ``append([1], [2], B)`` gives B = [1,2], so the thirs argument of append is always different of the second arg when the firs arg is different of the empty list.